# Text not arrived correctly on mail box

Tags: javascript, html

I use this code below

```
<!-- Message Body Input -->
<div class="row mb-1">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
      <textarea name="rawMessageText" type="text" rows="12" cols="40" 
      class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
</div> <!-- / message input -->
```

And when we send mail with the textarea input text like "elle va arrivée" it's showing on mail like "elle va arrivÃ©e" this type text not arrived perfectly and this problem only with webmail.

Comment: This is an encoding issue, and it happens when the text is utf but is treated as latin-1.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615704/french-characters-encoding-issues-%C3%A8-is-displayed-as-%C3%83%C2%A8-in-java, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942023/%C3%83-instead-of-%C3%A9-definitely-dont-know-why, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208517/java-%C3%A9-becomes-%C3%83-how-to-fix-it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it and https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%C3%A9+as+%C3%83%C2%A9